# Change text in mini cart and wishlist buttons on header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have looked everywhere for an answer to my issue but no one seems to have the same issue im having.

I have a wordpress site: http://valaidp.com/officechairtest/

The site needs to be everything in spanish, but the minicart and the wishlist in the header both say: "No products in the wishlist." and "No Products in the cart. And i want to change these to spanish, i have already tried looking through the files in the YITH wishlist plugin, and also on the woocommerce mini-cart and i have no luck changing theese.

Anybody that could help me know how to change these would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to find "No products in the wishlist" in project?

Comment: Actually i did find the file that had all these options, it was on the theme folder, called woo.php

Thanks! :D

Comment: If this is solved, please put the answer below, and accept it with the tick icon. Thanks!